# tar fail mode: Not exiting on write fail

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command, tar

I would like to know why tar is not exiting on a mkdir error. I am measuring the time it takes to untar the linux kernel multiple times, until it fails. I am using the tar command inside the while loop condition statement.

Here is the command I am running:

```
while sudo /usr/bin/X11/time -a -o out tar -xvf /home/USER_NAME/linux-3.12.tar -C /hdd3/; do sudo mv /hdd3/linux-3.12/ /hdd3/linux-3.12_`date +%s`; done
```

Here is the kind of error I get:

```
tar: linux-3.12/net: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device
```

I get the above error and many more for similar locations.

Basically, I am trying to get the while loop to exit as soon as tar can no longer untar the linux kernel into the /hdd3 directory. The body of the while loop changes the directory name of where the linux kernel was just created.

I want to this while loop to exit when tar is unable to write any further.

Answer (score 0):

Your tar, time or sudo must be faulty, not returning the correct exit status. My tar (GNU tar 1.27.1) finally says

```
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

and exits with status 2.

You might check the exit status of tar, time and sudo to find out the culprit.